# How to redirect a webpage to another webpage by random number?

Tags: javascript, html

Just wanted to know how by random number can I redirect a webpage to another webpage. 
In HTML I would do it like that way:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="seconds; url=http://example.com/" />
```

If the max range is 1.5 and the min range is 0.5, (from 0.5 to 1.5) for example, how can I insert it instead the "seconds" value? Simple quite question.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the question how to generate a random number or how to redirect to another page in javascript?

Comment: The question is how to generate a random number and inherit into the "seconds" value. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var second = parseInt(Math.random()* (1500 - 500) + 500);
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://example.com/" },second);
```

UPDATED mistaken js random to php rand
this one works tested in http://jsfiddle.net/3SNxg/

Comment: I don't know why, it doesn't work. I've also changed the seconds values to bigger values to 3000-min and 5000-max, to check if the problem is the random number (because I thought that maybe that random number is always 0.5) but I was wrong. It actually doesn't work.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: updated the answer , sorry i though js random takes min and max like php rand

Answer (score 1):

that is very easy.

just set the content to empty and then using jquery:

```
randomSecond = Math.random(2, 5); // ranges from 2 to 5 seconds

$('#metaID').prop("content", (randomSecond+"; myLinktoThatPage")  );
```

This approach is of course used in case you want to fill the meta tag, but there is `window.location.href` used in conjunction with setTimeout that can help you to redirect the page in raw JS.

But if you do not use jQuery and need raw Javascript:

```
randomSecond = Math.random(2, 5); // ranges from 2 to 5 seconds

document.getElementById('MyMetaTagID').setAttribute("content", randomSecond+"; myLinktoThatPage");
```

Comment: Generally speaking, unless the OP has added jQuery as a tag or specifically called out jQuery as being an acceptable requirement, it shouldn't be assumed as an available framework for the answer.

Comment: no I have put the javascript code without jQuery in the edited answer

Comment: you can accept it as an answer for later visitors if it works

Comment: I know it, thanks, I would like to have some other advices that can maybe be shorter and more helpful. Your way is awesome, but I want to  test the best answers to accept them for the next visitors. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following :

```
var meta_refresh = document.createElement("meta");
meta_refresh.setAttribute("http-equiv","refresh");
var random_delay = 0.5 + Math.random();
meta_refresh.setAttribute("content",random_delay+"; url=http://example.com/");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(meta_refresh);
```

Comment: Works, but it seems that the random number isn't random. I mean, the transition between the webpages seems the same, any time. Is that possible?

Comment: I dont think anyone would be able to tell the difference between a page refreshing after 0.5s and one refreshing after 1.5s. To make the random delay more evident, I suggest increasing the random delay duration. For example, for a random duration between 1 and 5 seconds, try : random_delay = 1 +(4*Math.random());

Comment: I checked, in my transition page there's a gif loader and it stops in exactly point every time. Weird. Anyway, the second way has showed me that it works. Thank you!